# In Pygame, how to give different attributes to a circle in a while loop?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, pygame

I am creating a NBA simulator similar to Haxball, in which each circle should have a user name and be its own thing so that during the running of the program an indiviual circle could have its own attributes changed e.g a player gets slower but not everyone does.

I have used a few lines in the teams class to create the **Player** and put them in a **team1players** list. This does work in creating 5 circles all in different co-ords. However I need the **playername** attribute (from the **Player** class) to change for each circle as only certain players play certain positions. I have tried to use **self.composition** in the for loop but it wont allow me to use a dictionary as an int. I need each player created to be a different playername - with the playername deriving from the composition dictionary containing all positions. So far I have added 1 name (Jose Calderon) to the point guard slot in the composition and I have tried to use the point guard list in the creation of the circle however this results in all players being named Jose Calderon as opposed to just **team1players[0]** (being the point guard) called Jose.

Below is the section of code I need help with - there is plenty of other flaws but this is a basic prototype:

```
self.team1players = []
for i in range(numPlayers):
    self.team1players.append(Player('Ruari', 15, random.randint(0,470),random.randint(0,500), Team1Colour, 0, Team1Name, 0.01, 30))
self.team2players = []#
for i in range(numPlayers):
    self.team2players.append(Player(self.composition['point guard'], 15, random.randint(470,940),random.randint(0,500), Team2Colour, 0, Team2Name, 0.01, 30))
```

Below is the full code as it will probably be needed for anyone to understand what is happening. Its a bit messy at the minute, sorry. :'(

```
import pygame
import random
import math
pygame.init()#initialising python

(width, height) = (940,500)#variables for screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) #sets the screen size as "screen"
pygame.display.set_caption('Basketball Simulator') #sets the title of the window
background_image = pygame.image.load("bballcourt.jpg") #setting the background image as a variable to be used to display on the screen
icon_image = pygame.image.load("basketball-tiny.png") #setting the icon image

numPlayers = 5

class teams():

    def __init__(self, teamname = "unknown", wins = "0", losses = "0", team1player = "unknown", team2player ="unknown", colour = "255,255,255"):
        #above I have created all the attributes of teams
        self.teamname = teamname #sets teamname
        self.composition = {
            'point guard' : [],
            'shooting guard': [],
            'small forward': [],
            'power forward': [],
            'centre': []
        }
        self.wins = wins #number of wins
        self.losses = losses #number of losses
        self.team1player = team1player #holds a player and can be used to create players I have made this here so that the players are a part of the team
        self.team2player = team2player

        self.colour = colour #holds the rgb colour specific to the team

    def startTeam(self):
        validTeamChoice1 = False #creating a while loop to only allow valid inputs for the first team choice
        validTeamChoice2 = False #loop for second team choice
        userChoice1 = " " 
        Team1Colour = userChoice1
        Team1Name = " "
        userChoice2 = " "
        Team2Colour = userChoice2
        Team2Name = " "
        while validTeamChoice1 == False:
            userChoice1 = self.teamname = input("Please select a team // GSW or CAVS: ") #allowing user input
            if userChoice1.upper() == "GSW":
                userChoice1 = self.teamname = ("Golden State Warriors")
                Team1Colour = self.colour = (0,107,182) #rgb colour for GSW yellow
                Team1Name = self.teamname
                if userChoice1 == self.teamname:
                    validTeamChoice1 = True
            else:
                validTeamChoice1 = False #continues loop
        while validTeamChoice2 == False:
            userChoice2 = self.teamname = input("Please select an opposing team // GSW or CAVS: ")
            if userChoice2.upper() == "CAVS":
                userChoice2 = self.teamname = ("Cleveland Cavaliers")
                Team2Colour = self.colour = (134,0,56) #rgb colour for CAVS red
                Team2Name = self.teamname
                self.composition['point guard'].append('Jose Calderon')
                if userChoice2 == self.teamname:
                    validTeamChoice2 = True
            else:
                validTeamChoice2 = False

        self.team1players = []
        for i in range(numPlayers):
            self.team1players.append(Player('Ruari', 15, random.randint(0,470),random.randint(0,500), Team1Colour, 0, Team1Name, 0.01, 30))
        self.team2players = []#
        for i in range(numPlayers):
            self.team2players.append(Player(self.composition['point guard'], 15, random.randint(470,940),random.randint(0,500), Team2Colour, 0, Team2Name, 0.01, 30))
    def displayPlayers(self): #displays the player using the player attributes and the display method from the Player class
        for n in range(numPlayers):
            self.team1players[n].displayCircle() 
            self.team2players[n].displayCircle()
    def printPlayers(self):
        print(self.team2players[1].playername)

class Player(): #the player class holds information on the player symbol
    def __init__(self, playername, size, x, y, colour, thickness,teamname,speed, angle): #teamname is predetermined
        self.playername = playername
        self.size = size #size is a unit for the radius
        self.x = x #x, y are position on the court 
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.angle = angle
        self.colour = colour
        self.thickness = 0 #thickness is set to 0

    def displayCircle(self): #drawing the circle onto the screen using colour, co-ordinates and radii
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size, self.thickness)




pygame.display.set_icon(icon_image)
screen.blit(background_image, [0,0]) #this sets the background court image (note: its outside all the classes) 
myTeam1 = teams() #creates a myTeam1 object from the teams class
myTeam1.startTeam() #runs the startTeam method from the teams class
myTeam1.displayPlayers() #runs the displayPlayers method from the teams
pygame.display.flip() #updates the screen based on current events ("flip" is the same as "update()")
myTeam1.printPlayers()
#the below code monitors current on screen events should they be needed for movement etc. it also allows the window to be closed.
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit
```

**Any help is appreciated!**

**EDIT** Below I have made it so that the relevant players are appended to their positions after the user has selected a team (each team has diff. players) and I have also created a new composition attribute in the teams class - now there's team1composition and team2composition so that both teams have a different point guard, shooting guard etc.   Is there a more efficient way? At first I planned to have both teams players in lists in the dictionary and I would use the array to select which player is for which team however I believe this is better?

```
class teams(): 

    def __init__(self, teamname = "unknown", wins = "0", losses = "0", team1player = "unknown", team2player ="unknown", colour = "255,255,255"):
        #above I have created all the attributes of teams
        self.teamname = teamname #sets teamname
        self.team1composition = {
            'point guard' : [],
            'shooting guard': [],
            'small forward': [],
            'power forward': [],
            'centre': []
        }
        self.team2composition = {
            'point guard' : [],
            'shooting guard': [],
            'small forward': [],
            'power forward': [],
            'centre': []
        }
        self.wins = wins #number of wins
        self.losses = losses #number of losses
        self.team1player = team1player #holds a player and can be used to create players I have made this here so that the players are a part of the team
        self.team2player = team2player

        self.colour = colour #holds the rgb colour specific to the team

    def startTeam(self):
        validTeamChoice1 = False #creating a while loop to only allow valid inputs for the first team choice
        validTeamChoice2 = False #loop for second team choice
        userChoice1 = " " 
        Team1Colour = userChoice1
        Team1Name = " "
        userChoice2 = " "
        Team2Colour = userChoice2
        Team2Name = " "
        while validTeamChoice1 == False:
            userChoice1 = self.teamname = input("Please select a team // GSW or CAVS: ") #allowing user input
            if userChoice1.upper() == "GSW":
                userChoice1 = self.teamname = ("Golden State Warriors")
                Team1Colour = self.colour = (0,107,182) #rgb colour for GSW yellow
                Team1Name = self.teamname
                if userChoice1 == self.teamname:
                    validTeamChoice1 = True
            else:
                validTeamChoice1 = False #continues loop
        while validTeamChoice2 == False:
            userChoice2 = self.teamname = input("Please select an opposing team // GSW or CAVS: ")
            if userChoice2.upper() == "CAVS":
                userChoice2 = self.teamname = ("Cleveland Cavaliers")
                Team2Colour = self.colour = (134,0,56) #rgb colour for CAVS red
                Team2Name = self.teamname
                self.team2composition['point guard'].append('Jose Calderon')
                self.team2composition['shooting guard'].append('J.R Smith')
                self.team2composition['small forward'].append('LeBron James')
                self.team2composition['power forward'].append('Jae Crowder')
                self.team2composition['centre'].append('Kevin Love')
                if userChoice2 == self.teamname:
                    validTeamChoice2 = True
            else:
                validTeamChoice2 = False

        self.team1players = []
        for position , name in self.team1composition.items():
            print (position, name)
            self.team1players.append(Player(name, 15, random.randint(0,470),random.randint(0,500), Team1Colour, 0, Team1Name, 0.01, 30))
        self.team2players = []#
        for position, name in self.team2composition.items():
            print(position , name)
            self.team2players.append(Player(name, 15, random.randint(470,940),random.randint(0,500)
```

When the code is now ran here is the result (not the Pygame window)...

```
Please select a team // GSW or CAVS: gsw
Please select an opposing team // GSW or CAVS: cavs
point guard []
shooting guard []
small forward []
power forward []
centre []
point guard ['Jose Calderon']
shooting guard ['J.R Smith']
small forward ['LeBron James']
power forward ['Jae Crowder']
centre ['Kevin Love']
```

Comment: maybe use `for position in self.composition:` or `for positon, name in self.composition.items()` instead of `for i in range(numPlayers)`

Comment: BTW: instead of `for n in range(numPlayers): self.team1players[n].displayCircle()` you can do `for player in self.team1players: players.displayCircle()` - it is more readable.

Comment: BTW: read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks, I know its really poorly structured but i dont have much experience in OOP and this is prototype for a large project I need done in 10 weeks. Yelp :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
for i in range(numPlayers): 
    self.team2players.append(Player(self.composition['point guard'], ...))
```

you can use `for` with `dictionary`

```
self.team2players = []#

for position, name in self.composition.items():
    #print(position, name)
    self.team2players.append(Player(name, ...))
```

---

**BTW:**

Because you have only one player in `self.composition`
so it will create only one player in `self.team2players`.

Dictionary doesn't keep order so when you will have more players in `self.composition`
then `for ... in self.composition` may create players in different order.

---

**EDIT:**

When I look at `Player(self.composition['point guard'],` then it seems you have only one string assigned to `self.composition['point guard']` and previous code should works,
but when I look on your dictionary it seems you have list with many names assigned to `self.composition['point guard']`:

```
    self.composition = {
        'point guard' : [],
        'shooting guard': [],
        'small forward': [],
        'power forward': [],
        'centre': []
    }
```

and it means you need two `for` loops

```
self.team2players = []#

for position, names_list in self.composition.items():
    #print(position, names_list)
    for name in names_list:
        #print(name)
        self.team2players.append(Player(name, ...))
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you will keep only one name for every position then you don't need list   but you can use string with name or empty string (or `None`) if there is no name.

```
self.composition = {
    'point guard' : None,
    'shooting guard': None,
    'small forward': None,
    'power forward': None,
    'centre': None
}
```

and you assign name without `append()`

```
self.composition['point guard'] = 'Jose Calderon'
```

and to create player you need use `if` to check `None`

```
self.team2players = []

for position, name in self.composition.items():
    if name: # the same as `if (name is not None) and (name != "") and (name != 0) and (name != False) ...: 
        self.team2players.append(Player(name, ...))
    #else:
    #   print("you don't have player on position", position)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was playing around with using the dictionary in the for loop but I got a few errors. It seems your way is better. In the future the user will input a team choice and then corresponding players will be assigned to 'point guard' or 'shooting guard' etc. this means there should hopefully never be more than 1 string in the lists in the dictionary. Perhaps i'm misunderstanding your point, are you considering this?

Comment: if never be more than 1 string there you don't have to create list but assing string with name or empty string (or `None`) and check if you have empty string (or `None`) before you create new `Player`

Comment: I put new example in answer.

Comment: I have used the for self.composition method you stated. Now I have added two compositions (1 for each team). There is now a team 1 composition and a team 2 composition they can be differed between based on users input. I'll edit the question so you can see :)

Comment: don't edit question - after that answers will not fit to question. Better create new question with button `Add Question`

Comment: you can add here link to new question.